# How should we reverse the twice as ... as?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request

I know we can say

- A provides twice as much performance as B does

Using the exactly same structure, the coordinating conjunctions, how can I reverse this? Is it OK to write

- B provides twice as less performance as A does.

Comment: No--B provides *half as much* performance. However, we don't usually use *much* with *performance*: "A provides half the performance of B", "B provides half the performance of A".

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks, but my problem is with that as .... as structure. I know we can say twice as many as .... I don't know how to reverse the sentence.

Comment: Don't 'reverse' the comparator, invert the multiplier: *A has twice as many children as B* = *B has half as many children as A*.

Comment: @StoneyB I see. Thanks. If I had smaller fractions, then should I said "one-fourth as many as children"?

Comment: You understand it perfectly.

Comment: Oddly enough, it is fairly common for native speakers to produce things like "three times less than ...." (I have even seen it in news reports).  However, "a third as much as" (or, for countables, "a third as many as") is greatly preferable and much more logical.

Comment: @rjpond The point is (was) how to reverse "a third as much as"

Comment: I thought your question was how to reverse "twice as much as".  Then we made the point that "four times as much as" reverses to "one-fourth [*or* one quarter] as much as".  I simply observed that "four times less" is commonly encountered, although illogical.

Comment: B  provides **three times less** performance than A: it's reversed now. There's nothing incorrect about three times less [some uncountable]. For a countable: three times fewer....:)

Comment: @Lambie: There's everything incorrect about multiplying a negation.  In most cases it just makes no sense (this includes your example).  In cases where it does make sense, it doesn't mean what you want.  If a glass is 90% full, it's 10% empty.  One-third as full is 30% full.  Three times as empty is 70% full, and *not* a valid way of saying 30% full.  For a countable, if your account balance is twelve dollars, then "three times fewer" is negative twenty-four, not positive four (that is, X=12, "Y fewer"=X - Y, three times fewer=X - 3X).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I would prefer:

> "A" provides twice **the** performance "B" does.

This makes the reverse of the sentence much more obvious:

> "B" provides *half* the performance "A" does.

So I haven't changed the word you perhaps expected to change, but I have kept the sentence structure the same.

"*Twice as much performance*" may be used idiomatically by some, but I don't think it is strictly correct. "Performance" is not a measurement in itself. The *overall performance* of a machine/computer/engine is something that takes into consideration measurements of many other things. Each device or whatever has its own performance level, and when you compare them you should ideally refer to "*the performance of*" each thing.

"*Twice as less*" is just simply incorrect.